# Export function calls in a separate file

Tags: javascript, import, module, export

I have the following function in my **app.js**. Now I want to "store" the function calls in a different file.

```
// Add .rellax class and data attribut
function addRellax(selector, value) {
    // get all elements that match our selector
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector); // add .rellax class to all chosen elements
  
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].classList.add('rellax');
    } // control speed
  
  
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].setAttribute('data-rellax-speed', value);
    }
  }
;

// Add parallax to elements
// I want to store the following three lines in a different file
addRellax('.helloWorld__item1', 6);
addRellax('.helloWorld__item2', -2);
addRellax('.helloWorld__item3', 3);

// Init 
const rellax = new Rellax('.rellax');
```

I created a file called **helloWorld.js** and tried it with:

```
export default
addRellax('.helloWorld__item1', 6);
addRellax('.helloWorld__item2', -2);
addRellax('.helloWorld__item3', 3);
```

and replaced this part in my **app.js** with

```
// Add parallax to elements
import './05-sections/helloWorld/helloWorld.js';
```

but I got the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: addRellax is not defined at Object../src/05-sections/helloWorld/helloWorld.js`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the functions to be invoked in helloWorld.js you would want to import app.js to helloWorld.js.  Just by importing helloWorld.js to app.js, it does not run that js file, it allows you to access the code within that file.

What is the reason that you want to invoke them in a different js file?

Comment: "helloWorld" is an example for a component where I want to use the parallax effect. I have a folder for every component (with a separate php, css and js file) and there I want to add ```addRellax('.classname', 1);``` to each component where I want to add the parallax effect.

Comment: maybe it's a bad idea to write the function calls in separate files :) i think i will put it all in one parallax-config.js

Answer (score 0):

If your function is in the app.js file you should export it from the app.js file:

```
export default addRellax;
```

and then you can import it wherever you'd like to import with:

```
import addRellax from 'app.js path';
```

where in app.js path is your path to your app.js file

Answer (score 0):

You will need to import app.js in helloWorld.js in this case

export addRelax from App.js

```
function addRellax(selector, value) {
    // get all elements that match our selector
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector); // add .rellax class to all chosen elements
  
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].classList.add('rellax');
    } // control speed
  
  
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].setAttribute('data-rellax-speed', value);
    }
  }
;

// Add parallax to elements
// I want to store the following three lines in a different file
// we will store below three in hellowWorld.js
//addRellax('.helloWorld__item1', 6);
//addRellax('.helloWorld__item2', -2);
//addRellax('.helloWorld__item3', 3);

// Init 
const rellax = new Rellax('.rellax');
export default addRellax;
```

try in hellowWorls.js

```
import addRellax from 'App.js' //provide correct app.js file path
// Add parallax to elements
// I want to store the following three lines in a different file
export const addRellaxItem6 = addRellax('.helloWorld__item1', 6);
export const addRellaxItem2 = addRellax('.helloWorld__item2', -2);
export const addRellaxItem3 = addRellax('.helloWorld__item3', 3);

//or you can export at once as object 
export default {
   addRellaxItem6,
   addRellaxItem2,
   addRellaxItem3
}
```

add addRelax function in hellowWorld.js instead or any other file then you can import addRelax anywhere you want.

if i want relax related code to be used in multiple places there will be a relax related util file
ex: relaxUitl.js

```
//relaxUtil.js
export const rellax = new Rellax('.rellax');//now this instance can be imported anywhere
export function addRellax(selector, value){ //import anywhere you want to use
//addRelax related code
}
export const addRellaxItem3 = addRellax('.helloWorld__item3', 3);

//or you can export at once as object 
export default {
   addRellaxItem6,
}
```

Comment: hmmm the ````const rellax = new Rellax('.rellax');```` must come after the lines in helloWorld.js.. how would this be possible? but helloWorld.js is just one example of many  other files with the same function calls so I can't write the »const rellax« in the helloWorld.js